# Memory increase and program quit

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, linux-kernel

I am writing a python program, and when I test it, at the first 20 minutes, it works fine, then suddenly the memory consumption increase a lot from 1G to more than 6G, then it ended with no error. I guess it might be killed by kernel because both memory and SWAP are full. 
Here is my question, 1. how do I know why it quit? 
2. Is there anyway I could know why it suddenly consumes so much memory? 
The code is more than 800 lines and I don't which part I could simplified, so I didn't paste it here. 
Basically the program is just a big loop doing the same thing to different data.

Here is the last moment before it crashes, [image]

I don't know the why the VIRT suddenly goes so high, but before this happens, there is also some strange phenomenon, since the whole program is using 30 threads with proxies to crawl some websites, the normal traffic is around 1MB/s, but traffic before this happens is around 10MB/s, even 20MB/s (the speed is possible, since I am testing on a VPS), but traffic when this is happening is almost 0. I don't know how to link the traffic and memory problem together.

Comment: What does your program do, and how (roughly speaking)?

Comment: it starts 30 threads to crawl a website, and do some analysis. At first I can see the memory usage increase steady, but all of a sudden, it is mad.

Comment: and are you pretty confident that there is a sudden jump from 1G to 6G at the 20min mark? Or could it be a more gradual increase? And what are the time periods you're using, e.g. between collections or whatever?

Comment: not exactly 20 min, the time varies, but I do see the sudden increase, there is slow gradual increase as I am aware because I am storing things in RAM, but the sudden increase does exist, just after the increase, the program exit with no error. what do you mean by your second question? Currently I am testing on another machine to check this. @HumphreyTriscuit

Comment: I had assumed you were scheduling your data pulls on regular time intervals, but I may be wrong of course

Comment: No code, no reopen, sorry buddy. How are we to know why this happens without seeing what abomination you are committing?

Comment: there are more than thousand of lines in several files, am I supposed to paste them here?

Comment: I found the problem, because several threads downloaded big video file (the original url was not video, but redirects to a video), which caused the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can start with Python line profiler, it is used to see how fast and how often each line of code is running in your script.

```
pip install line_profiler
```

Once you time it, you can start analyzing memory

```
pip install -U memory_profiler
pip install psutil
```

The quickest way to find “memory leaks” is to use an awesome tool called objgraph This tool allows you to see the number of objects in memory and also locate all the different places in your code that hold references to these objects.

```
pip install objgraph
```

Comment: Thank you for reply! That's indeed very useful tool, but I am looking for reason why this happens and hoping someone with similar experience could help me. But I will definitely accept your answer if no one could help me.